# Can you have an image instead of text for a button?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a button on my webpage that creates a link popup for copying. Is it possible to use an image instead of text on the button? I would like to use the "Link" image (image of chains) that you can see on the main Google Maps webpage or something similar. Thank you.

```
<input type="button" value="Email Link" onclick="showLink()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="image" src="myimage.jpg" onclick="showLink()" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was looking for something more similar to the google maps Link button that has a chain link image superimposed on the button rather than an image that acts as a button. Or is it possible to have an image (such as a chain link) along with the text "Email Link" on a button?